# How can i stretch swf video to fit the player in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, flash

I have made a program to play some swf file... Now my current code is:

```
        //Make program fullscreen, etc
        axShockwaveFlash1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        InitFlashMovie(axShockwaveFlash1,Properties.Resources.SWF);
```

Now till that we are good but the problem is i get 2 black bars on the right and left... How can i make my SWF fullscreen and get rid of these black bars? I need a better way to resize axShockwaveFlash1

Comment: Keep the width/height proportional to the original SWF size.

Comment: but in most websites the game is stretched... looks amazing... Once i download the game from the website it becomes super small

Comment: Also when i make the control bigger manually(Using form editor) the game is stretched but i want the size to be as same as the form

Comment: I have no idea what you see... (1) Do the borders get less if you **increase** display height of SWF? (2) Do you have a screen grab of your form/app? (I want to see swf display size / proportions). (3) Do you have a link to a site where the game is stretched nicely?.

Comment: Solved.. thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: @Emily, if it's solved then you need to answer your question and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by dynamically generating the control at runtime